# Alkaline Phosphatase

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, enzymes

What is the predominant purpose of *Alkaline Phosphatase* in skeletal muscle fibers and liver cells. I know that it is a hydrolase enzyme that speeds up the degredation of proteins, lipids, starch and other biomolecules. But what does it does it **specifically** do in muscle and liver cells. And why is it in higher concentration in the liver ? Is it because of the livers purpose as an organ (cleanse and detoxification) ? Therefore pino/or endocytosis occur in higher rates ? I appreciate anyone with any intelligent insight.

Comment: http://pharmascope.org/ijrps/downloads/Volume%204/Issue%203/08-10265.pdf

Comment: It has a very wide role and there are multiple types of alkaline phosphatases...